# Taking tobacco and nicotine products to the USA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, drugs, florida

Can I still bring tobacco and/or nicotine products to the USA / Florida and if so, how much? I am not a US citizen. I am over 21 years old. Most interested in nicotine products, maximum 4 mg of nicotine.

Original title & post:

> #### Tupakan ja nikotiinituotteiden vienti USA
>
> Voiko USA / Floridaan  vielä tupakkaa ja tai nikotiinituotteita ja jos niin kuinka paljon?

Comment: We are an English language site and all posts have to be in English. This time an other user has provided a translation but you should have done that yourself.

Comment: Are you an American citizen? Is it for personal use or for trading?

Comment: There is plenty of advice to be found for returning US citizens, such as in [Customs Duty Information](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/international-visitors/kbyg/customs-duty-info). But I can't see anything about non-residents.

Comment: Are you 21 or over?

Comment: I am not a US citizen. I am over 21 years old. Most interested in nicotine products, maximum 4 mg of nicotine

Answer (score 3):

Finally [a site that describes what visitors to the USA are allowed to bring in](https://www.snowbirdadvisor.ca/what-items-can-canadian-snowbirds-bring-us).

> Visitors may import up to 200 cigarettes and 100 cigars into the U.S. duty free. However, cigars must not be from Cuba.

It doesn't say there is an age limit (it does give one for alcohol) but it's probably best to assume that if you can't legally buy tobacco (i.e. aged under 21) then you also can't bring it in. That's the rule stated for returning residents.

Comment: The pedant in me wonders whether _cigarettes_ from Cuba are ok?

Comment: I think the pedant would be justified in asking, but I'm pretty sure would get the answer "no". The site I quoted said "cigars" but the official wording is "tobacco products".